# How do I pass a GET function into View/ViewModel? How do I bind data to View (with only C# code)?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, blogger, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to setup Google's Blogger API into Xamarin Forms. Google has only Windows Phone samples. I just need to reconfigure to get the data and bind it to the view. I am not sure how to pass the GET function into ViewModel and bind the response in the View.

So this is the Blogger API code sample to get the data.
[Google Blogger API:Repository.cs](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/Blogger.Sample/Blogger.Sample.Shared/Repository/BloggerRepository.cs)

This is ViewModel to pass the repository function.
[Google Blogger API:BlogsViewModel.cs](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/Blogger.Sample/Blogger.Sample.Shared/ViewModel/BlogsViewModel.cs)

My main question is: Is it supposed to be like this BindingContext in XF View?

```
BindingContext = new BlogsViewModel(new BloggerRepository());
```

Comment: I just don't know what to pass in that BlogsViewModel.

Comment: This should be correct, have you tried it out?

Comment: I would like to know how you got authorization working with Xamarin and the Google .net client library any chance you would be willing to post that code?

Comment: I haven't got to the point of accessing the Google API yet in this case. Yes. You can use Google API in Xamarin app. Some Google API have certain ways of authorization to their API. I've used Youtube API in my app. Please go through the Google Samples code. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Xamarin, but ideally you should have the view model call the api in a separate service file. Store the result of that service call in a property in the view model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, then bind that property in the xaml.

There's no reason to use the code behind unless there's something particular to Xamarin forms I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Binding the data to the view with default value, and update the value in the ViewModel when you get the data from Blogger API.

Pass a `new BloggerRepository()` should work, what you need to do is create 
 a mode with properties(Like Name,ID,Title,Content) and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. When get data from `GetBlogsAsync/GetPostsAsync`, update the values in the `ViewModel`.

See the document about how to implement data binding in MVVM: [data-bindings-to-mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)